# How to find out which new permissions are required by an update?

Tags: permissions

When updating an app that requires new permissions, those new permissions used to be labelled with a green `NEW` tag. No more. Now I can only see the full list of permissions required. I'm still prompted to confirm the change, but I can't save time by only looking at the new ones.

Without manually keeping track of the old permissions and other impractical ideas, is there a workaround? A way to see what changed before I install the update?

Comment: As far as I know if it it has new permissions it advises there are now ones, and makes you accpet them before installing. I tried it on Play 4.8.20 and it did indeed bring up the message. What version of Play and Android are you using?

Comment: I believe there is an xposed module that gives more control over the play store updates.

Comment: @RossC no that's correct, I see the same. It asks me to confirm again, but it shows the full list of permissions, without showing which ones I confirmed the last time, requiring me to check them all again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the app details page, you can scroll to the bottom of the page. You will find a link under PERMISSIONS saying "View details". That will open a popup page that will display all the permission categories with expanded view and list all the permissions the app needs, including the new ones required with "NEW" tag.

Comment: And so you can! Brilliant. Just a note for future visitors: this is not available from the permissions prompt; you have to go and open the app's details page.